# MySql -How do you use multiple WHERE clause with OR as well

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

ive been searching for hours on how to correctly do this but not getting any good results so thought id try my luck and ask you guys. So here is my script:

```
$q = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = ? AND membership = ? AND confirmation = ? AND alpha_status = ? AND approved = ? AND type = ? OR type2 = ? OR type3 = ? OR type4 = ? OR type5 = ?");
$q->bindParam(1, $yes);
$q->bindParam(2, $good);
$q->bindParam(3, $good);
$q->bindParam(4, $good);
$q->bindParam(5, $yes);
$q->bindParam(6, $search);
$q->bindParam(7, $search);
$q->bindParam(8, $search);
$q->bindParam(9, $search);
$q->bindParam(10, $search);
$q->execute();

$howMany = $q->rowCount();
```

So everything works but it just grabs everything in the database. Im guessing the multiple OR isnt working. What i am trying to achieve is the amount of users that pass the search the criteria. With "type" all users have 5 type's added to their account. it can be Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta Echo etc. so where one users type2 is Bravo another user might have Bravo in type5. So im trying to get the total amount of users that have Bravo as a type. Hope ive explained it will. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use parenthesis to establish operator precedence:

```
 AND approved = ? AND (type = ? OR type2 = ? OR type3 = ? OR type4 = ? OR type5 = ?)");
```

Comment: THANKS i cant believe thats all i had to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `in` which simplifies the query by only requiring that `$search` be included once

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE status = ? AND membership = ? AND confirmation = ? AND alpha_status = ? AND
      approved = ? AND
      ? in (type, type2, type3, type4, type5)
```